# Openlayers - Vector Layer - Combining hide/show features using style property

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, filter, style

I am trying to filter vector layer features according to their attributes. I have 4 check boxes: type_1, type_2, shape_1 and shape_2 Note that I am using Extjs for interface.

at beginning I could filter type attribute setting style to 'none' or '' ... like so :

```
switch (f) { 
case 'type_1': 
if(checked) 
filter('show_type_1'); 
else filter ('hide_type_1); 

case 'type_2': 
if(checked) 
filter('show_type_2'); 
else filter ('hide_type_2); 

} 

function filter(value) 
{ 
 switch (value){ 

case 'hide_type_1': 
for (i=0;i<=features.length;i++) 
if(features[i].attributes.type == 'first') 
features[i].style = 'none'; 
layer.redraw(); 

case 'show_type_1': 
for (i=0;i<=features.length;i++) 
if(features[i].attributes.type == 'first') 
features[i].style = ''; 
layer.redraw(); 

case 'hide_type_2': 
for (i=0;i<=features.length;i++) 
if(features[i].attributes.type == 'second') 
features[i].style = 'none'; 
layer.redraw(); 

case 'show_type_2': 
for (i=0;i<=features.length;i++) 
if(features[i].attributes.type == 'second') 
features[i].style = ''; 
layer.redraw(); 

} 
}
```

all above works great, if I uncheck type_1, all type_1 features will diappear. then if I uncheck type_2, all type_2 features will diappear. then if I check type_1 again, all type_1 features will appear, and type_2 features will stay hidden.

The problem is when I tried to do the same with shape attribute, by adding:

```
case 'shape_1': 
if(checked) 
filter('show_shape_1'); 
else filter ('hide_shape_1);
```

to the first function.

and:

```
case 'hide_shape_1': 
for (i=0;i<=features.length;i++) 
if(features[i].attributes.shape == 'first') 
features[i].style = 'none'; 
layer.redraw(); 

case 'show_shape_1': 
for (i=0;i<=features.length;i++) 
if(features[i].attributes.shape == 'first') 
features[i].style = ''; 
layer.redraw();
```

to the second one.

it works when I uncheck the shape_1 checkbox. all shape_1 features hid. but if check it to display them, all features will be displayed even type_1 and type_2 which I was keeping them unchecked and hidden!

I don't understand why that happens. because it works fine if I handle one attribute (type in my case) but failed when tried to combine type filtering with another feature attribute (shape).

I hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the JavaScript `switch` - `case` construct incorrectly. You need to add a `break` statement at the end of each `case` block, e.g.

```
switch (f) { 

    /* ... */

    case 'type_2': 
        if (checked) {
            filter('show_type_2');
        } else {
            filter ('hide_type_2);
        }
        break;

    case 'shape_1': 
        if (checked) {
            filter('show_shape_1');
        } else {
            filter ('hide_shape_1);
        }
        break;

}
```

Note that the `case` keyword only marks the beginning of execution, and the next `case` keyword does not mean the end of execution. You have to use `break` or `return` if you want to leave the `switch` block once it was entered.